# C# .NET4.0 TableAdapter.Update() won't insert new record

Tags: c#, .net, insert, adapter, bll

I have a small application which consists of a DAL, BLL and the Application itself all in different projects under one solution in Visual Studio 2010.

My DAL is using an xsd file to query the database and my BLL has methods to get the information from the DAL and do stuff with it.

Currently I am trying to insert a record using the code behind of the application to make a call to a method in the BLL which then attempts to insert the record by using the Tableadapter.Update() method generated in the xsd file of the DAL.

I can already select and update records with no problem, but I can't insert records.

As far as I know the TableAdapter.Update() method should know to insert a new record if I provide it with a new row, however it is returning a value of 0 - meaning 0 rows were affected, so it isn't working.

The table I am trying to insert into is called tblRoles.

It has an 'ID' column, which is an int, primary key and identity column. It has a 'Name' column which takes nvarchar(50), and it has 4 'CanAdduser' etc columns which take a type of bit.

Here is my code:

APP code behind:

```
protected void CreateRole(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    RolesBL roles = new RolesBL();

    roles.CreateRole(NewRoleName.Text);

    RolesGridView.DataBind();
}
```

BLL:

```
private tblRolesTableAdapter adapter = new tblRolesTableAdapter();

public bool CreateRole(string Name) {
    CMSDS.tblRolesDataTable roles = new CMSDS.tblRolesDataTable();
    CMSDS.tblRolesRow row = roles.NewtblRolesRow();

    row.Name = Name;
    row.CanAddUsers = false;
    row.CanEditUsers = false;
    row.CanSuspendUsers = false;
    row.CanChangeUserPasswords = false;

    int result = adapter.Update(row);

    if(result == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

From what I understand this should insert a new row into the table, but `adapter.Update(row)` keeps on returning a 0 and I don't know why.

When I debug I can see that all of the row columns have been assigned the correct values, and no errors are thrown.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that when I configured the default Fill,GetData() query in the xsd file I did make sure that it auto generated Insert, Update and Delete statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added the new Role-Row to the DataTable.

```
CMSDS.tblRolesDataTable roles = new CMSDS.tblRolesDataTable();
CMSDS.tblRolesRow row = roles.NewtblRolesRow();
row.Name = Name;
roles.AddtblRolesRow(row); 
int result = adapter.Update(roles); //the same as `adapter.Update(row)`
```

Comment: +1; this makes more sense than my answer.  It seems other (single table?) examples don't call `AcceptChanges`.

Comment: Brilliant! You have saved me a lot of frustration :) Thank you! To be honest I wasn't really sure how it all worked so I didn't even know that Add~Row() method even existed.

Comment: @Merlyn: `adapter.Update` will implicitely call `AcceptChanges`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx